# OS X: Creating RAMDisk in root

Tags: macos, ramdisk, read-only

How would I create a RAMDisk on OS X for a read-only filesystem, so that any attempted writes to the drive (which is read-only) are directed to the RAMDisk instead?

Comment: Is this a read only disk (I.E> a CDROM) or a DMG file (Disk Image?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want a [UnionFS](http://rentzsch.com/macosx/unionFilesystems) mount...

I'm not sure exactly how you'd do this, most likely you'd create a RAM disk, put a DMG file on that, and then mount the DMG with `hdiutil attach -union / file.dmg`

Comment: Glad that worked for you!

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few articles that explain how you can create a RAM disk:

- you can create a RAM disk using the [Make RAM Disk](http://boredzo.org/make-ram-disk/) utility,
- this article over on [macosxhints.com](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20020530084607311) gives instructions on how you can create a RAM disk larger than 2.2 GB

The part about the redirection is a bit trickier, I'm not sure how you can do it.

Comment: Thanks, and yeah, creating the ramdisk isn't that hard. The second part is a bit tougher...

Answer (score 1):

This line is a keeper...  it may not be exactly what the OP was looking for, but it will surely make someone happy.  And there's a lot you can learn for it too.

```
diskutil erasevolume HFS+ "ramdisk" `hdiutil attach -nomount ram://1165430000`
```

Comment: I suggest you explain what it does, in detail, if *it may not be exactly what the OP was looking for*.

Comment: It's an answer to the first part of the OP's question, "How would I create a RAMDisk on OS X ..."     It will create and format a HFS+ ramdisk, then mount it as /Volumes/ramdisk.   The big number at the end changes the size of the ramdisk.  It's in sectors or something I can never remember.

Comment: This article explains more details on the command line way: https://blog.macsales.com/46348-how-to-create-and-use-a-ram-disk-with-your-mac-warnings-included/